# Making Android phone locked using the SIM card password

Tags: sim-card

When I press the power button. the Android phone will go into sleep mode.

When I press the power button again, the Android phone will wake up and ask me a password.

So, how do I make the Android phone ask me the password that belong to the SIM card instead of the phone itself?

What I mean is that the SIM card was locked with a password. The phone itself was not locked with any password (also not locked in pattern password). So, how do I make the Android phone prompt me the password of the SIM card every time when I wake it up regardless if I just power up the android phone or I just wake it up from a sleep?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to just set a password and make it the same numbers as your SIM password?

Comment: because I don't want to change the password two times (one time for the SIM password and another time for the phone) for every month (cause I change my SIM card password every month)

Comment: If your goal is better security, then by using the same password for phone and SIM lock, you are actually making yourself less secure for the sake of convenience.

Comment: Chahk has a point. Having 1 password for both defeats the purpose have having one for each. If I get the password I have access to the entire phone, rather than just the phone/sim.

Comment: @BlaineAnderson I do agree that if it is for security sake, then it would defeat the purpose of having 1 password. I was just wondering if Android have such feature (or function). If Android does not have such function, I really don't mind setting 2 password.